# GetDefinition in as3 using sprite class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have a problem. I have been able to run my game successfully using as3isolib library (IsoSprites), but when i search on the internet, the IsoSprites don't have the hitTestObject or hitTextPoint features. So, i changed the IsoSprites to the Sprite, but when i already changed the IsoSprites to the Sprite, i am getting this error:

> 1119: Access of possibly undefined property sprites through a
>   reference with static type flash.display:Sprite.

and it is pointed in:

> Constant.dudeEfis.sprites = [efisFrontClass];
>
> dudeEfis is Sprite

i am aware that the Sprite don't have the feature of:

> dudeEfis.sprites

but the problem is, if i change the "dudeEfis" to the IsoSprite, i am not be able to get the hitTestObject or hitTestPoint. And if i change to the Sprite, i am getting that error. How do i solve it? The code that i am giving to you is for movement faces direction (when the player is facing south, so do the character)

Here is the code:

```
public static var loaderEfis:Loader;
public static var dudeEfis:Sprite; //public static var dudeEfis:IsoSprite;
public static var _numXEfis:Number = 0;
public static var _numYEfis:Number = 0;

Constant.loaderEfis = new Loader();

Constant.loaderEfis.load(new URLRequest("efis.swf"));

var efisFrontClass:Class = Constant.loaderEfis.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("EfisFront") as Class;

if (Constant._numXEfis == 0 && Constant._numYEfis == 0)
{
    Constant._numXEfis = Constant.dudeEfis.x;
    Constant._numYEfis = Constant.dudeEfis.y;

    Constant.dudeEfis.sprites = [efisFrontClass];
}
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should change your question title. It has nothing to do with `GetDefinition` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you already know what the problem is. One way you can solve this is to create your own class that extends the `IsoSprite` class then add the `hitTestObject` and `hitTestPoint` methods yourself, they're pretty easy to implement.

```
package {
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class MyOwnSprite extends IsoSprite {
        public function hitTestObject (object:DisplayObject):Boolean {
            //some logic here
        }

        public function hitTestPoint (point:Point):Boolean {
            //some logic here
        }
    }
}
```

This way you get to keep all the functionality of `IsoSprite` while having those two methods that you need.

Comment: So, i have to access the collision in that MyOwnSprite extends IsoSprite class?

And, that object represents all of the IsoSprite? How do the system know that which IsoSprite refer to? Example i have 2 IsoSprites, and want to only access the first IsoSprite, how do i do that?

Comment: or should i make use of intersect? because in IsoSprite, there is an intersect function.. Is it intersect is the same with hitTestObject and hitTestPoint?

Comment: @Kaoru Yes, if you extend `IsoSprite` you will get all its public properties and methods. As for the library itself I can't answer those questions because I've never heard of or know how this library works. You will have to consult the documentation for that.